# How can an IP address be statically assigned in Ubuntu 15.04 server?

Tags: networking, server, 15.04

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 mini in a Virtualbox VM with the network bridged.  The install automatically enables DHCP which works fine.  In order to statically assign an IP address, I edited /etc/network/interfaces to look like the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.168.1.218
  gateway 10.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.254.0
  dns-nameservers 10.168.1.210
```

If the networking service is restarted, the static address works fine.  On reboot, eth0 is up and an ifconfig shows the correct IP, but I can’t ping other devices, i.e. the gateway, and other devices can’t ping this machine.  A simple ifdown/ifup cycle will kick it back in gear as will the networking service restart, but I’m hoping to find a way to make the static ip assignment work upon reboot.
I’ve looked at the syslog and didn’t see anything unusual regarding eth0.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, find your Ubuntu Server's internal MAC Address (All servers have them) and write it down

1- Open a web browser
2- Go to your router using your IP Address
3- Login to your router

**WARNING: SETTINGS MIGHT BE SLIGHTLY DIFFERENT, JUST USE YOUR INNER CHRIS COLUMBUS AND FIND THE SETTING PAGE**

4- IP And MAC Binding
5- Add a new one
6- For MAC Address put your server's address
7- For IP, put the static IP you want to give it **(REMEMBER THIS IP)**
8- Restart your router
9- Go to the settings of your Ubuntu Server and set the IP to the Static One (The one that you set as the bound IP in your router)
10- Restart the computer
11- BAM! You're done!

Comment: I'm hoping to find a way that doesn't involve the router if possible.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why? And if so, you're out of luck, assigning a static IP is 95% of the time done router side.

Comment: It can be done in 14.04, just trying to figure out how to do it in 15.04